# Implementing d3 Codeflower source code

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm trying to replicate this visualization here http://redotheweb.com/CodeFlower/ using my own json data. However the visualization is not showing up and I suspect it's because I have misplaced this block of code

```
var myFlower = new CodeFlower("#visualization", 300, 200);
myflower.update(jsonData);
```

which updates the visualization based on the content in the jsonData file. The full code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
    <div class = "content">
        <div class = "container">
            <p class = "lead"> </p>
            <div id = "visualization">
                <svg width = "270" height = "270">
                    var myFlower = new CodeFlower("#visualization", 300, 200);
                    myflower.update(jsonData);
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type = "text/java
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/d3/d3.geom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/d3/d3.layout.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/CodeFlower.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/dataConverter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> </script>
</body>
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't go in an `<svg>` tag. Place it in a `<script>` tag instead.

Comment: tried that but this too doesn't work:
`<script
   var myFlower = new CodeFlower("#visualization", 300, 200);
   myflower.update(jsonData); </script>`

Comment: You are missing a closing `>`. It should be `<script> //code here</script>`

Comment: fixed that too. i have the jsonData and javascript files in the same folder so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Is your script at the *end* of the page (after all the other script links?) or is it still in the middle?  Scripts are executed in the order they appear, so you can't tell the browser to execute the "code flower" method until after you have loaded in the "code flower" script.  See the links to MDN I gave in my answer so you can get an overview of how Javascript is interpreted by the browser.

Comment: yes, my latest version is like the one suggested by @t.888 below but it still doesn't work.

Comment: If you're using it exactly as below, I suspect the problem is that the `src` urls are referencing files on the server from the website whose code you've copied -- unless you have all the files in the same locations on your computer (and a localhost server set up to supply them) it's not going to work.  Please read the MDN Intro to Javascript and/or Scott Murray's "D3 Setup" tutorial.

Comment: @AmeliaBR all files (html, js, json files) are in the same directory so I'm still not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: Without details about what errors you are getting or not on the developer's console ([Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_JavaScript) or [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)) it is hard to say.  If you are working with files on your own computer, your browser's security settings are probably preventing any scripts from accessing your local files.  Google "local host web server" and your computer operating system name to find out how to set up a local server for testing purposes.

Comment: One more thing -- I just copied your code above into a [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/DJmhC/), and realized there was a typo: `myFlower` with a capital F on the first line, but then `myflower` all lowercase on the second line.  Once you make them match, it works in the fiddle.  If it's still not working at home, check the local web host issue.

Comment: @AmeliaBR, thank you. I'm now seeing the nodes but the lines are missing. I see that you added some CSS to render the lines. is that necessary? i would think the original script is complete.

Comment: @AmeliaBR, also, how would i do it if the json data in a separate file?

Comment: You'll need to have some CSS to see the lines. See the fiddle at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @t.888 is correct, the CSS is required -- default style for SVG does not display "strokes", which means lines are not visible.  For accessing the json file, replace my `getData()` method with a [`d3.json(filename, function)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests) call where the function contains the two lines of code to draw the graphic (i.e., just take the example code from that link, and replace the filename and then replace `visualizeit()` with your code).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not quite correct. I think you can dispense with the SVG element, and move your CodeFlower initialization code to the empty script tag. Try this instead:

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
    <div class = "content">
        <div class = "container">
            <p class = "lead"> </p>
            <div id = "visualization">
              <!-- this empty div is what gets used by CodeFlower -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.geom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.layout.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="CodeFlower.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dataConverter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myFlower = new CodeFlower("#visualization", 300, 200);
        myFlower.update(jsonData);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

According to the [documentation](http://redotheweb.com/CodeFlower/):

> **Usage**
>
> To create a CodeFlower, include the CodeFlower.js file together
>   with d3.js, just like in this page. Create a new CodeFlower instance
>   using a CSS selector (*of the div where the flower should be inserted*),
>   and the width and height of the desired visualization. Then, bind JSON
>   data to the flower using CodeFlower.update(), and you're done.

CodeFlower creates the SVG element itself, inside the DIV that you provide. From the CodeFlower source code:

```
this.svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg:svg")
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);
```

So adding your own SVG tag for CodeFlower is superfluous.

EDIT:

Make sure you have a valid jsonData variable: `var jsonData = { /* json data here */ };`

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2DUy9/1/

Comment: thanks but i tried the code you provided but it still doesn't work. any other thoughts?

Comment: I added a working example to the bottom of my answer. Everything seems to work fine, but you'll need some json data for CodeFlower to operate on. See the provided fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The block of code you're talking about is javascript, so it needs to be within script tags -- you've got a nice empty one at the end of your code.  As is, your "code" is just being read as plain text.  If it was inside a regular HTML element, the code would be displayed as text on the webpage, but text inside an SVG tag isn't even understood as plain text, since SVG is supposed to contain graphics.

Within the script you have to then indicate which SVG element you want to add the graph to.  Just putting some code in the middle of your HTML doesn't make the results of the code go there -- even if it was put inside a script tag.  However, the code you are borrowing is looking for the `<div id="visualization"></div>` tags, and should draw it there once you get your script formatted as @Colin recommended -- but only if your little bit of script comes *after* the script tag that imports the CodeFlower script.  Otherwise, you'll just get an error in the console and nothing on the screen.

I'm afraid you're going to have to take some time to figure out what all the different parts of the program do before you can effectively adapt them to your needs.

The Mozilla Development Network has some good intro guides:

- [On HTML markup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction)
- [On Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide)

For D3, the best intro for beginners without coding experience is the work of Scott Murray:

- http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/